# When a path is associated to more routes, which route is used?

Tags: 8, routes

How does Drupal 8 decide which route to use, if there are two routes defined in Drupal 8 via routing.yml that lead to the same path?

Of course this sounds like a stupid idea or like a mistake in code to have two routes with same path. But I think about having one route with a parameter and a second route without parameter but with a path that the first route might deliver.

So for example there is node.add route in node.routing.yml

```
node.add:
  path: '/node/add/{node_type}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::add'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::addPageTitle'
  requirements:
    _node_add_access: 'node:{node_type}'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node_type:
        with_config_overrides: TRUE
```

Now I am defining a route myexamle.nodeadd in myexample.routing.yml like this

```
myexample.nodeadd:
  path: '/node/add/examplecontenttype'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::add'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::addPageTitle'
    node_type: 'examplecontenttype'
  requirements:
    _node_add_access: 'node:examplecontenttype'
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node_type:
        with_config_overrides: TRUE
```

I added an additional _requirement in the second route. This is working for me like this, but I actually did not get how Drupal decides which of the two routes to actually use.

Comment: Seems first the more specific route, then the one with the wildcard, no?

Comment: Yes, that sounds good and would be the way I prefer it to be :-). But I could not find some evidence about that, so wanted to be sure to understand this properly.

Comment: Yeah, could be module weight as well.

Comment: Yes, the more specific route wins because it has a higher fit value, evidence [RouteCompiler::getFit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteCompiler.php/function/RouteCompiler%3A%3AgetFit/8.6.x)

Comment: Ah, yes there it is. If you like to put it as an answer I will accept it. Or if you not like, I can do and accept the answer. Kudos to @4k4!!

Comment: The kudos belong to @Berdir who shared this knowledge first, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223329/how-to-solve-a-situation-where-two-or-more-routes-with-different-controllers-poi